# How to append a js from an external js in a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a page that calls an external `application.js`. This external `application.js` file should call an external `join.js` (hosted on a third party domain) and place it inside a given div on the page i.e. `#myGivenId`.

**Updated**: Simplified problem explanation.

The `join.js` file simple return a `document.write('something here');` string. The `something here` text should be placed inside the `#myGivenId`

I'm tried the following code but the result does not appear to be rendered on the page nor appears on the source code.

```
// jQuery version
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $.getScript('http://localhost:3001/ads/join.js', function(script) {
    return $('#myGivenId').html(script);
  });
});

// CoffeScript version
$(document).ready ->
  $.getScript('http://localhost:3001/ads/join.js', (script) -> $('#myGivenId').html(script))
```

Any idea why is not appearing?

Comment: What is the intent? Display the javascript source or execute the javascript? If you want to display the source, why are you using a script tag? If you want to execute it, why does it have to be in a div?

Comment: Not the source, the idea is to execute it and display the result inside the box (it should drag a div with contnet inside `#myGivenId`)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code for join.js. I believe you are misinterpreting the functionality of `$.getScript()`.

Comment: @dtbarne the code of join.js is simply `document.write('something here');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `$.getScript` does not return data that way, you need to provide a callback.

```
$(document).ready ->
    $.getScript(script_url, (data) -> $('#myGivenId').append(data));
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: That doesn't seem to add the result of the .js inside `#myGivenId`. I don't even see the result in the code at all (nothing found searching the code through inspector).

Comment: I believe you meant `$(document).ready`, not `$('#myGivenId').ready`. Right, Sanketh? To quote the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): "The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document."

Comment: Ah yes, thanks Trevor, I had copied the original question, just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is putting the `div` into the DOM. This is easily fixed:

```
document.body.appendChild(placement);
```

Put this line at the end of you function.

Comment: Not sure how that would solve the problem? I'm already appending the script to the placement in my sample provided. Please elaborate on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by the "result" of the script, but here are a few possible solutions (forgive my Coffee Script, I normally program in JavaScript):

### Exported function

Assuming the script has a function you want to call, just use jQuery's .html():

```
$('#myChosenId').html(someFunc())
```

You'll have to make sure that the script is loaded ahead of time:

```
$.getScript(pathToScript, () -> $('#myChosenId').html(someFunc()))
```

This will load the script and then call the function when it's loaded.

### Eval

If the script is just an expression (like `5 + 3` or `callSomeFunc(Math.cos(5), 7, "hello")`), then I'm afraid the only solution is to use `eval`.  This is **NOT** a good solution, and I highly recommend refactoring the code, if possible, to export a function.

```
$.get(pathToScript, (script) -> $('#myChosenId').html(eval(script)))
```

`$.get` will *hopefully* get the raw script (you might need to use `$.ajax` if that doesn't work) and pass it to your callback. `eval` will execute the script and assign whatever the "result" is to the div.

From your question, this sounds like what you wanted. I never recommend using `eval`; I just provided it for completeness.

If you're doing something like this often, then I'd recommend looking into [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). It allows you to structure your code cleanly and import external code in a safe way.

**Edit:**

### Embed script tag into element:

```
$('#myChosenId').append($('<script>').attr('src', pathToScript))
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. It's just creating a new script tag under your element. This is terrible style, and you should probably find a different way of getting the data from that 3rd party site. Sometimes it's necessary, such as for working with router firmwares or the like.

Comment: Trying with eval() I get a ' XMLHttpRequest cannot load url' error. The script url is located on a third party site.

Comment: The script simply return a `document.write('some html content')`

Comment: @Martin - See edit. I haven't tested it, but it should work, theoretically.

Comment: It doesn't. It does not insert the `script` tag inside the div. I tried changing the `<script>` for `<p>` just to test and it does insert when passing a `<p>` tag. Seems like its preventing from adding a `script` tag somehow using this method (?)

Comment: Don't you mean a `script` tag?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work how you are expecting it to. document.write() will write to the body from where the original script was placed in it. You can't `document.write()` to an element...you'd need to modify an element's `innerHTML` instead.

If you're not able to edit join.js, you don't have a good solution other than to change the positioning of the original external script.

If you can change join.js, modify it to modify the DOM directly. eg.

```
document.getElementById("myGivenId").innerHTML = "something here";
```

Comment: I can modify `join.js` but `join.js` should have no reference to a specific ID name other than its `<script>` parent. This is because of the way join is embedded: `<script src="http://site.com/join.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you use a variable in one of the prior scripts that join.js can use?

Comment: Not sure how it would work, could you elaborate? There are two scenarios to embed join.js a) simply adding `<script src="http://site.com/join.js"></script>` will render where it's placed. b) through javascript loading the file and providing an id (`#myGivenId`) as Im trying to do with no success. I can edit join.js but I should keep the join.js abstraction clean.

Comment: For example, the initial page or application.js could set `window.useThisID = "myGivenId";". Then join.js would just have document.getElementById(window.useThisID).innerHTML = "something here";